# Mongo DB MapReduce: Emit key from array based on condition

Tags: performance, mongodb, mapreduce

I am new to mongo db so excuse me if this is rather trivial. I would really appreciate the help.

The idea is to generate a histogram over some specific values. In that case the mime types of some files. For that I am using a map reduce job.

I have a mongo with documents in the following form:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5ed3e67960de6794dd21c"),
    "name" : "some name",
    "uid" : "some app specific uid",
    "collection" : "some name",
    "metadata" : [
        {
            "key" : "key1",
            "value" : "Plain text",
            "status" : "SINGLE_RESULT",
        },
        {
            "key" : "key2",
            "value" : "text/plain",
            "status" : "SINGLE_RESULT",
        },
        {
            "key" : "key3",
            "value" : 3469,
            "status" : "OK",
        }
     ]
}
```

Please note, that in almost every document there are more metadata key values.

**Map Reduce job**

I tried doing the following:

```
function map() {
   var mime = "";
   this.metadata.forEach(function (m) {
     if (m.key === "key2") {
        mime = m.value;}
     });
     emit(mime, {count:1});
}

function reduce() {
  var res = {count:0};
  values.forEach(function (v) {res.count += v.count;});
  return res;
}

db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out: { inline : 1}})
```

This seems to work for a small number of documents (~15K) but the problem is that iterating through all metadata key values takes a lot of time during the mapping phase. When running this on more documents (~1Mio) the operation takes for ever.

So my question is:
Is there some way in which I can emit the mime type (the value) directly instead of iterating through all keys and selecting it? Or is there a better way to write a map reduce functions.

Something like emit (this.metadata.value {$where this.metadata.key:"key2"}) or similar...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two thoughts ...

First thought: How attached are you to this document schema?  Could you instead have the metadata field value as an embedded document rather than an embedded array, like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fc5ed3e67960de6794dd21c"),
    "name" : "some name",
    "uid" : "some app specific uid",
    "collection" : "some name",
    "metadata" : {
        "key1" : {
            "value" : "Plain text",
            "status" : "SINGLE_RESULT"
        },
        "key2": {
            "value" : "text/plain",
            "status" : "SINGLE_RESULT"
        }, 
        "key3" : {
            "value" : 3469,
            "status" : "OK"
        }
     }
}
```

Then your map step does away with the loop entirely:

```
function map() {
   emit( this.metadata["key2"].value, { count : 1 } );
}
```

At that point, you might even be able to cast this as a "group" command rather than a "mapReduce".

Second thought:  Absent a schema change like that, particularly if "key2" appears early in the metadata array, you could at least exit the loop eagerly once the key is found to save yourself some iterations, like so:

```
function map() {
   var mime = "";
   this.metadata.forEach(function (m) {
     if (m.key === "key2") {
        mime = m.value;
        break;
     } 
     });
     emit(mime, {count:1});
}
```

Not sure if either path is the key to victory, but hopefully helpful thoughts.  Best of luck!

Comment: Hi,

thank you for your reply. The suggestion with the break is not feasible, because the metadata key value pairs can be rather long and this will not necessarily improve performance. 

However, I changed the schema as you proposed (with a slight app-specific modification) and now the filtering within the map reduce is much easier. The map function that you suggested works much better and I am able to obtain the histogram for almost 1.5 Mio records in less than a minute. 

So, I am accepting your answer! Thank you very much for your help!